# SIgnalR to group registration fails on Connect method

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub

I am using this part of code in the hub (with interface `IConnected`) of *signalr*. The problem is when I call `Group.Add` in `Connect` method, a client really isn't in the group and I can't send him a message throw this group. When I call later some method from the client to register in a group, everything is ok. What I don't understand, in both methods(in `Connect()` even in `registerClientToGroup()`) has the same `Groups.Add` method.

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task Connect()
{
  Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, "group");
  return null;
}
```

Some ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the direct cause of your problem, but I'm surprised you are not getting errors because you are returning a null value for the `Task` from `Connect`. You probably are getting errors, you're just not debugging/catching them.

If you don't have any other work to do in `Connect` that necessitates your own `Task` then simply return the `Task` from the call to `Groups.Add` like so:

```
public Task Connect()
{
    return Groups.Add(this.Context.ConnectionId, "group");
}
```